# Remove Entity with Many-to-Many Relationship in JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "account_transaction",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id"))
    Set<Transaction> listTransaction = new HashSet<>();
    public void removeTransaction(Transaction transaction){
        this.listTransaction.remove(transaction);
        transaction.getListAccount().remove(this);
    }
}
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "listTransaction")
    Set<Account> listAccount = new HashSet<>();

    public void removeAccount(Account account) {
        this.listAccount.remove(account);
        account.getListTransaction().remove(this);
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void remove() {
        for (Account account : this.getListAccount()) {
            account.getListTransaction().remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

```
  @DeleteMapping("account/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteAccount(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        var a = accountRepo.findById(id).get();
        a.listTransaction.forEach(transaction ->  a.removeTransaction(transaction));
        accountRepo.delete(a);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("transaction/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteTransaction(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        transactionRepo.deleteById(id);

    }
```

output :

> Hibernate: select t1_0.id,l1_0.transaction_id,l1_1.id from transaction t1_0 left join (account_transaction l1_0 join account l1_1 on l1_1.id=l1_0.account_id) on t1_0.id=l1_0.transaction_id where t1_0.id=?
> Hibernate: select l1_0.account_id,l1_1.id from account_transaction l1_0 join transaction l1_1 on l1_1.id=l1_0.transaction_id where l1_0.account_id=?
> Hibernate: select l1_0.transaction_id,l1_1.id from account_transaction l1_0 join account l1_1 on l1_1.id=l1_0.account_id where l1_0.transaction_id=?

I've got two classes, "account" and "transaction," connected through a many-to-many relationship. When I remove an account or a transaction, I intend for the associated entry in the "account_transaction" table to also be removed.

why this code doesnt acheive that ?

Comment: [jpa-remove-entity-many-to-many](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-remove-entity-many-to-many)

Comment: actually i used this article the write my code but it didnt work for me

Comment: have a look here [many-to-many-association](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-the-best-way-to-remove-entities-from-a-many-to-many-association/)